# My Cypress Reports Folder does not get properly deleted when I execute the rmdir command in the package.json file. Which command should I use?

Tags: browser-automation, test-automation-framework, cypress

I am running Cypress on a Windows machine.

I am using this command (included in the ***package.json*** file) to remove the ***cypress/reports*** folder before the start of each test run:

```
"clean:reports": "IF EXIST 'cypress\\reports'(rmdir /Q /S cypress\\reports) && mkdir cypress\\reports\\ && mkdir cypress\\reports\\mocha\\ && mkdir cypress\\reports\\mochareports\\"
```

Upon analysis, I've seen that the ***cypress/reports*** folder which stores the test report folder does not get deleted even after the above mentioned script executes.

Am I using the correct command? What command should I use to ensure that the system checks for the ***cypress/reports*** folder to be present, and if yes deletes it successfully?

Comment: I believe [`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) is cross-platform, why not use something like that?

Comment: @srini: can't you just leave out the check for existence? The rmdir command seems ok (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd), I use it in the same way, but I do not have the if statement there. I mean why checking for existence where there's no else statement then.

Comment: Did the answer help

Comment: @PDHide Yes it did. Thanks very much. pavelsaman , I agree. The If condition saves the need for manually checking if the reports folder exists or not. But that is just a one time action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap if exists with bracket:

I also made some cosmetic changes, please use below script

```
"clean:reports":"(if exist cypress\\reports (rmdir /Q /S cypress\\reports)) && mkdir cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports\\mocha  &&  mkdir cypress\\reports\\mochareports"
```